# 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'reserve_distance'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have been trying to retrieve data from database using prefetch_related including a Many-to-Many relationship. However, I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `reserve_distance` on serializer `ProjectIndianReserveSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `ManyRelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'reserve_distance'.
```

When removing `reserve_distance` from ProjectIndianReserveSerializer (considering this is a Many-to-many relationship there is a possibility to have zero records), the serialization finishes with no errors showing an empty result after serialization:

```
 "nearest_first_nations": {
   "reserve_id": null
 },
```

However, when running the created query (shown below), a record for the project_id =1 exists in the db:

```
SELECT ("project_nearest_first_nations"."project_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_project_id",
       "indianreservebanddistance"."id",
       "indianreservebanddistance"."reserve_id",
       "indianreservebanddistance"."reserve_distance"
  FROM "indianreservebanddistance"
 INNER JOIN "project_nearest_first_nations"
    ON ("indianreservebanddistance"."id" = "project_nearest_first_nations"."indianreservebanddistance_id")
 WHERE "project_nearest_first_nations"."project_id" IN (1)
```

I am wondering why is not showing the record in response when I have the record in the db:

```
_prefetch_related_val_project_id|id |reserve_id|reserve_distance|
------------------------------------+---+----------+----------------+
                                   1|110|       627|         31.1900|
                                   1|111|       660|         39.5800|
                                   1|112|       607|         46.1700|
```

Here is the configuration I have in the models:

indian_reserve_name.py (model)

```
class IndianReserveName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
```

project.py (model)

```
class IndianReserveDistance(models.Model):
    reserve_id = models.ForeignKey(IndianReserveName,
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                   db_column="reserve_id",
                                   null=True)
    reserve_distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=4, blank=False, null=False)


class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    nearest_first_nations = models.ManyToManyField(IndianReserveDistance,
                                                   db_column="nearest_first_nations",
                                                   blank=True,
                                                   null=True)
```

With the following serializers:
get.py (serializers)

```
class ProjectGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nearest_first_nations = ProjectIndianReserveSerializer(required=False)
    
class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            "project_name",
            "nearest_first_nations",
        )
```

distance.py (serializers)

```
class ProjectIndianReserveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IndianReserveDistance
        fields = ('reserve_id','reserve_distance')
```

and the view:
list.py (View)

```
class ProjectList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProjectGetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Project.objects.all()

        return queryset.prefetch_related('nearest_first_nations')
```

Do you know how to get the data in the response? Have been searching and I have not found any solution yet.

When iterating over queryset to print nearest_first_nations, I am getting:

```
{'_constructor_args': ((<Project: Project object (1)>,), {}), 'creation_counter': 81, 'model': <class 
'models.project.IndianReserveDistance'>, 'name': None, '_db': None, '_hints': {}, 'instance': <Project: Project object (1)>, 'query_field_name': 'project', 'prefetch_cache_name': 'nearest_first_nations', 'source_field_name': 
'project', 'target_field_name': 'indianreservedistance', 'symmetrical': False, 'through': <class 'models.project.Project_nearest_first_nations'>, 'reverse': False, 'source_field': <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: project>, 'target_field': <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: indianreservedistance>, 'core_filters': {'project__id': 1}, 'pk_field_names': {'project': 'id'}, 'related_val': (1,)}
```

If changing fields to `'__all__'` in `OpportunityIndianReserveSerializer`, I have still the same problem `'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'reserve_distance'.`

Do you have any clue how to get reseve_id and reserve_distance?

Thanks a lot